# Order Optimization with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with products available in pack configurations like:

```
SKU   PACK
xyz     25
abc    250
```

A user can select the number of items they want in multiples of 25. I'd like to be able to fill an order using the largest packs possible. For example if a user wants 275 products then I would fill the order with 1 of the abc sku and 1 of the xyz sku. If a user wanted 225 products then I would fill the order with 9 xyz.

I'm having trouble approaching the problem and am looking for suggestions on an approach. Pseudo-code or PHP would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation of the classic [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). The Wikipedia article provides a lot of technical background on all the variations, but this is a rather simple variation. The following might be a good approach:

1. Retrieve an array of all possible pack configurations ordered by pack size in descending order.
2. Iterate over the list of pack sizes.
3. Subtract whole multiples of the current pack size from the item count until the item count is less than the pack size. Maintain a count of the number required of that pack size.
4. When you reach the end of the list, the remainder should presumably go into the smallest pack.

Answer (score 0):

well, just need to find the largest sku that is less then or equal to products, find out how many of that sku fit into products, multiple that answer by the sku packs, and subtract that from the total. any remander, loop.

```
$order = array();
do {
 $row = $db->query("select sku,pack from table where pack = (select max(pack) from table where pack <= $products)");
 $order[$row[sku]] = floor($products / $row[pack]);
 $products -= $row[pack] * $order[$row[sku]]
} while($products > 0)
```